# Iterating through an array of objects and displaying the values in textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

I have to loop through an array of objects and display the values in textarea. Below is the code i tried so far:

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div class="container" ng-repeat="i in items">
    <div class="containerDescription">
        <textarea ng-model="i.name" 
          style="height:120px; width:200px;"></textarea><br>

    </div>
```

The values are getting displayed in different textareas. How to display the values in the same textarea?Attached the plunkr link : http://plnkr.co/edit/DF2Na5vHd9SKu9MHQFvb?p=preview

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Angular, but given your setup and behavior I'd assume that your loop is making a new instance of textarea based on your `ng-model` parameter. Would it work correctly if you moved the parameter to a element inside your textarea like `<textarea><p ng-model="i.name"></p></textarea>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you want to take advantage of two-way data binding, so that users entered manually into the `textarea` would appear in your model, then you may use a directive with custom [$formatter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) and [$parser](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) (to match your data structure):

```
angular.module('demo').directive('formatNames', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$formatters.push(function(users) {
          return users.map(function(user) {
            return user.name;
          }).join('\n')
      });
      ctrl.$parsers.push(function(users) {
          return users.split('\n').map(function(name, i) {
            return { id: i, name: name };
          });
      })
    }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9zXCyOUYjiRuIwcFwypz?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You do not need ng-repeat here, you could join all the elements with the folliwing and call the function

```
$scope.textAreaValues = function() {
    return $scope.items.map(function(elem) {
      return elem.name;
    }).join("\n");
 }
```

[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TyxXorvGICSzZE7WGtXU?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Saneetharan thanks for the solution.Instead of comma is there a way that i can display the values in the next line?